# Ugly Feynman diagrams from Tikz PART2

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-feynman, feynman

The following code,

```
\documentclass{article}
% lualatex

\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\begin{align}
\feynmandiagram[inline=(b), horizontal=b to c, layered layout]{
    a -- [blue, gluon] b [dot] 
    -- [blue, gluon, half left, looseness=1.5 ] c [dot] 
    -- [blue, gluon, half left, looseness=1.5 ] b, 
    c -- [blue, gluon] d};
\end{align}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

is producing the following Feynman diagram:

[image]

I find the loop a bit ugly since the gluon propagators have edges closer to the vertex and look tilted in the loop...
Can anyone give me improvement suggestions to make it more elegant and appealing?